# How do I buy cirque du soleil tickets with a non USA credit card?

Tags: tickets, payment-cards, las-vegas

In a few weeks I'm going to Las Vegas (from Belgium) and I would like to reserve some tickets for Cirque du Soleil (Ka).

I can select seats and everything, but when I get to the payment screen and enter all the correct data I still get and error saying `There is a problem with your payment, please check your credit card information`.

I am sure that everything if filled correctly (worked on other reservations). But I remember sometimes they do validation on addresses, is this the case? And if so, how am I able to reserve my tickets?

Comment: I would recommend getting really good seats.  The theater is massive, and despite having okay seats, it was hard for me to see some of the action.  I would also recommend the Circ show at New York, New York (Zumanity).  It is very inexpensive (in comparison), is in a small intimate theater, but is adult in nature (topless girls and simulated sex scenes).  However, it was my favorite of all the circ shows I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

You need to contact the issuer to find out why it's not completing.  They should have a record of the authorization request and response.

If not, then you will have to call the boxoffice and speak to an Agent.

Comment: When I travel abroad I need to let my credit card company know where I'm going. Otherwise they assume that an attempted transaction in another country is invalid and will decline it automatically.